# How to remove the missing data from the dataset and plot the scatter plot

Tags: python

My question is how to remove the missing data from the dataset and plot the scatter ,someone can help me solve this question please plot

Comment: Hi! I see you're a new contributor, welcome to SO. I advise you to check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please, avoid taking a picture of your screen as people will be more likely to answer a well posed question

Comment: Hi @okokmou, welcome to Stack Overflow!  There are some guidelines here about how to ask questions.  Please have a look at this and then update your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the lists you have into a dataframe `df` using [pd.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and then use [.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to drop the rows that have `nan` values and then in the end use [plt.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) from Matplotlib to plot the scatter plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

Hp = [10050, 42300, 50206, np.nan, 105000, np.nan, 22350]
nr = [np.nan, 4,5,6,10,12,2]

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Price':Hp,
        'Rooms':nr
        })
df = df.dropna(axis=0)

plt.scatter(x = df['Price'],y= df['Rooms'])
plt.xlabel('House Price')
plt.ylabel('Rooms')
```

[image]